# How to subscribe to multiple channels on Redis NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a function which I will call from time to time.

```
function blah() {
   sub.unsubscribe();
   sub.subscribe("a");
   sub.subscribe("b");
}
```

Above results in error message "Error: node_redis command queue state error."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

Once a connection is subscribed, it can only issue subscription related commands (subscribe, psubscribe, etc)
Might another part of your code be using the same connection?
You could also try and subscribe to multiple channels with one call `sub.subscribe("a", "b")` or subscribe to a pattern that matches your need?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [**redis**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).I was also facing the same issue in which i was trying to subscribe a set of channels.

```
var redis = require('redis')

const subscribe = redis.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
}) 
subscribe.psubscribe(`user:chat:*`)

subscribe.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log(channel, message, pattern)
    // Write Your Awesome Code here.
})
```

Psubscribe used for subscribing for multiple channels using redis. You can subscribe multiple channel on the basis of pattern.